# Mostrar en labels valores de Json almacelados en variable (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, json, class

Tengo esta clase:

```
public class Userinfo
{

    public Userinfo()
    {

    }
    public static async Task<List<Information>> Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string str = "https://somesite.com/log.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1)
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);
            return result;
        }
     }
  }
```

Que me devuelve este JSON correctamente:

```
[{"username":"fakeuser","email":"fakeemail@outlook.com","plan":"1","activationdate":"18\/12\/20","terminationdate":"18\/01\/21"}]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en un label en otro usercontrol el contenido de la variable `result`. Intenté de la siguiente forma pero el label me sale vacio.

Este es el codigo que tengo en el usercontrol donde tengo los labels:

```
private async void Filldata()
    {
        var result = await Userinfo.Login("username", "password");
        
        label11.Text = result.Select(x => x.username).FirstOrDefault();
        label18.Text = result.Select(x => x.email).FirstOrDefault();
        label19.Text = result.Select(x => x.plan).FirstOrDefault();
        label20.Text = result.Select(x => x.activationdate).FirstOrDefault();
        label21.Text = result.Select(x => x.terminationdate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Y esta es la clase donde se deserializa el JSON:

```
public class Information
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }

}
```

Cada clase es diferente, class Information es una y class Userinfo es otra. Y despues tengo el usercontrol que es donde quiero mostrar los labels como mencioné anteriormente.

Que estoy haciendo mal y como puedo solventarlo?

Comment: No debería ser eso, pero estoy un poco confuso.... ¿por qué usas streams/select en vez de simplemente `result[0].username` (quizás con una validación antes de que hayas recibido algún resultado)?

Comment: En todo caso, lo primero sería poner un log detrás del await para saber qué te está llegando.

Comment: O bien, ¿por qué no haces antes que nada `var value = result.FirstOrDefault()`, y luego de chequear por `null`, haces `value.username`, etc.? ¿Esa url siempre devuelve una lista con un único elemento? ¿Puede devolver dos o más? ¿No puedes evitar enviar la contraseña por la url, por lo que es muy visible?

Comment: `str2` siempre devuelve el Json que se le pide correctamente que es el que muestro mas arriba. si cuando debugeo coloco el cursor sobre `result` no me aparece nada. como si la variable no estuviera asignada

Comment: Luego de ejecutar la asignación, en la línea `return result`, ¿qué tipo y valor tiene? No puede aparecer "nada", algo tiene que tener.

Comment: [Pic](https://prnt.sc/wcdsai) Lamentablemente no se ve el cursor pero lo tengo encima de la variable y ese eso es lo que sucede

Comment: ¿Por qué `Login` es async? No hay ningún `await`, podría devolver la lista directamente. Estoy haciendo pruebas deserializando tu string y funciona lo más bien. ¿Y si abres el Quick Watch y pones `result`? ¿O en la ventana de Watch 1?

Comment: El `await` esta en el formulario donde ocurre el login. Userinfo es solo la clase. No entiendo mucho de Quick Watch. Aun estoy aprendiendo y lo estoy haciendo auto-didacta, por eso las dudas.

Comment: Haz click derecho sobre la variable y elige QuickWatch y te abre una ventana con el valor. O Add Watch, y se verá en la ventana Watch 1 (generalmente en la parte inferior de la pantalla). Si no, hazlo *"por las malas"*. Por ejemplo: `var primero = result.FirstOrDefault();` y `var usuario = primero.username;`, y mira qué sucede.

Comment: Haciendo lo que me comentas si busco la variable me dice "El nombre 'result' no existe en el contexto actual". Lo interesante es que si hago, por ejemplo `public static async Task Login(string Username, string Password)` en vez de `public static async Task<List<Information>> Login(string Username, string Password)` entonces si la variable se muestra correctamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117823/discussion-between-andrew-and-dragonsans-gameplays).